# how to query record with multiple condition using yii framework

Tags: mysql, yii

I want to get all the results satisfy (age=20, name=jim) or (age=30, name=allen) or (age=40, name=sam), how to write the query code with yii?

Comment: call $query->orWhere('age' => xx, 'name' => yy) in a foreach block, it works but not graceful enough

Comment: It's `yii2` or `yii1` **?**

Answer (score 2):

if you use yii 1:

```
$criteria = new CdbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('age = :age1 AND name = :name1', 'OR');
$criteria->addCondition('age = :age2 AND name = :name2', 'OR');
$criteria->addCondition('age = :age3 AND name = :name3', 'OR');
$criteria->params = [
    ':age1' => 20,
    ':age2' => 30,
    ':age3' => 40,
    ':name1' => 'jim',
    ':name2' => 'allen',
    ':name3' => 'sam',
];
$result = YourModelName::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: what if I add a constrain sex=male

Answer (score 1):

If you use yii2

```
$query->orWhere(['AND',
                  ['age' => 20],
                  ['name' => 'jim']
                ])
      ->orWhere(['AND',
                  ['age' => 30],
                  ['name' => 'allen']
                ])
      ->orWhere(['AND',
                  ['age' => 40],
                  ['name' => 'sam']
                ])
     ->all();
```